# GlassFish authentication basic username and PASSWORD

Tags: java, authentication, glassfish

I need to make protected resource on my GlassFish4.1 server.  Digest or basic authentication will be good. I need only one user to be created. I know, I could create user in admin-console, which is internal app-server application. Also there is possibility to create user via `asadmin` console command. But I'd like to have this one user in existing file, that will be packet to war with application. Is there a way to set user with password via `web.xml` or in some other internal file?

---

UPD:
my app is very simple and I do not use database.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this isn't directly possible. Container managed security always uses a realm (either the one you set up in `web.xml` or the default one) to get the user data and none of the existing realms gives you the possibility to specify users inside your web application.

You could easily implement a solution for this with the help of [filters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) or there may be some Java web authentication framework which already provides this functionality but I guess this would be overkill.